# How can I set value to a Material UI text field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, esri, recoiljs

I am creating an autocomplete search using EsriGeocode.
I am using Material UI. The form has 4 fields (Street name, City, State, and Zip code).
I am performing the search in the Street name text field. My problem is that I haven't been able to set the value in the Street name text field to be the street name only. It's showing the entire address.

How could I fix it?

Code can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-search-ocz1hw

Comment: do you mean that you are not able to set value of `street name` in the Street name field ? I tried running your sandbox and it seems to be working fine. Can you please give an example explaining your issue as well

Comment: @inkredusk Suppose you type this address (24 Keel Pt, Pooler, GA) in the street name. As soon as you select in the list of the options. I want the street name to show `24 Keel Pt`, the City to show `Pooler`, the State to show `GA`, the Zipcode to show `31419`. Right now, the issue is that the street name is showing the entire address.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `getOptionLabel` prop to the following

```
<Autocomplete
  // ...
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label.split(", ")[0]}
  // ...
/>
```

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I don't want the options to change. The options should be entire addresses. Upon clicking/choosing an address, the street name should be a street name, not the entire address.

Comment: My bad . I'll get back to you